# Python requests-html: Render html with cookies

Tags: python, python-requests-html

What I'm trying to do:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

with HTMLSession() as s:
    s.get('url', cookies=my_cookie_jar)
    s.html.render()
    print(s.html.html)
```

I want to access a page where I need to log-in. I already logged in using a selenium browser, where I then exported the cookies as a *RequestsCookieJar*.

Now when I print the text returned by the get-request, I receive the text of the correct webpage (but without the javescript rendered), but as soon as I render the html the cookies seem to have no effect and I get the html of a page asking me to log in (the same I get when issuing the request without the cookies in the first place).

**Now my question:**
Is it possible to specify the cookies when rendering the html (or should requests-html already do this by default)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you can, by using the kwarg cookies in render method.

```
s.html.render(cookies=my_cookie_jar)
```

Comment: Got `TypeError: HTML.render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cookies'`

Answer (score 0):

Solution, from Github (https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/109). Seems to work for me:

```
html.render(reload=False)
```